# Apache CXF 2.7.X to 3.1.11 upgradation

Tags: apache, cxf

In Apache CXF 2.7.18, apache providing HmacUtils.computeSignature ( String macAlgoOAuthName, String macSecret, String data ) [static] : String
but in  Apache CXF 3.1.11 this method is not available.One thing I know that they implemented HAWK algorithm at the place of MAC algorithm.Please tell any corresponding API for compute Signature in Apache CXF 3.1.11.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The method was simply doing:

```
    HmacAlgorithm theAlgo = HmacAlgorithm.toHmacAlgorithm(macAlgoOAuthName);
    return HmacUtils.computeHmacString(macSecret, 
                                       theAlgo.getJavaName(), 
                                       data);
```

You should still be able to use this part of code, only the method was removed as part of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5628.